# Store Spark DStream to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm working on Apache Spark Streaming (NO SPARK SQL) and I would like to store the results of my script on a mongodb.
How can I do that? I found some tutorial but they work only with Apache Spark SQL.

Thanks

Comment: First search result returns this: https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/streaming/

Comment: Are you trying to use this connector? https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark

Comment: The fact is that the mongodb-spark-connector use the apache spark streaming SQL libraries. I'm not using that kind of libraries. I'm using the standard Apache spark streaming library. @plambre

Comment: @maasg see the answer above